# NServiceBus.Core.Analyzer problem in multitarget csproj

Tags: c#, nservicebus, .net-standard-2.0

I have problem with my multitarget framework csproj. I need to have lower version of NServiceBus in net45 targeting, and latest NServiceBus version in netstandard 2.0. My *.csproj file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net452</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework) == net452">
    <PackageReference Include="NServiceBus" Version="5.2.24"></PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="NServiceBus" Version="7.1.6"></PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The problem is with the .NET Framework 4.5, because it doesn't see NServiceBus.Core.Analyzer.dll. When i try to compile solution, I get this error:

> 'C:\Users\.nuget\packages\nservicebus\5.2.11\analyzers\dotnet\cs\NServiceBus.Core.Analyzer.dll'

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: why? latest [version still supports 4.5.2 and .net standard 2.0](https://www.fuget.org/packages/NServiceBus/7.1.6)

Comment: there are so many breaking changes between NServiceBus version 5 and 7, I'd definitely not recommend trying to use these different versions within the same project.